# How to split strings with regex like {{(all spaces)variableValue(all spaces)}}

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, split

It is necessary to split the strings according to such a regex, but I cannot compose it.

Introductory line:

```
{{ text1  }} 123 {{text1}}{{text1}}  {{  text1}}134
```

Text in a variable:

```
const a = text1;
```

Split result:

```
["{{text1}}"," 123 ","{{text1}}","{{text1}}","  ","{{text1}}","134"]
```

Also, keep in mind that the word text1 is just the value of a variable that can change.

I tried to do it through new Regexp to insert the value of the variable there, but I still couldn’t do a normal split.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: Also do the spaces inside the curly bracket get trimmed?

Comment: @mplungjan Sorry, I'm not good at asking questions. Yes, what's inside the strings will be trimmed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one does not care what word is in the brackets

If you really want the space in element 4, we will need to test for one space before trimming

https://regex101.com/r/RMEeRd/1

```js
const input = `{{ text1  }} 123 {{text1}}{{text1}}  {{  text1}}134`;
const regex = /\{\{\s*([^}]+)\s*\}\}|([^{}]+)/g;
const matches = [...input.matchAll(regex)].map(match => match[0].trim());
console.log(matches)
```